# How do upload to the public folder on a website - c#

Tags: c#

Hi guys I hope someone can help me out. I had a program created. It does the following.

Downloads files from my site from a folder

puts the files in a temp folder on the HDD

uploads the files to a destination folder

deletes the temp folder and files.

Now everything works great. When you run the program you enter the ftp info, user,pass,host and destination directory

Now if the host is say ftp://mysite.com and the dir to put the files in is appz so the idea would be to create the folder in the public_html which is does then to upload the files to the new created folder however the ISSUE is when it uploads the files it doesn't go into the public_html folder instead it puts it in the root which is not accessible by url if you were to try to view it.

This is the function that does all the work I am hoping someone can see something I do not I will put the line of code that is the upload part in bold.

```
       public void CopyFilesBetweenFtpDirectories(string destHost, string destUsername, string destPassword, string destDirectory, BackgroundWorker worker)
    {
                   SessionOptions sessionOptionsSource = new SessionOptions
        {
            Protocol = Protocol.Ftp,
            UserName = username,
            HostName = "mydomain.com",
            Password = password,
        };
        SessionOptions sessionOptionsDestination = new SessionOptions
        {
            Protocol = Protocol.Ftp,
            UserName = destUsername,
            HostName = destHost,
            Password = destPassword
        };
        using (Session session = new Session())
        {
            // Connect
            session.Open(sessionOptionsSource);

            // Download files
            worker.ReportProgress(10);
            session.GetFiles("/domainwithfiles.com/AppFiles/*", Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"\Downloaded_files_from_ftp\*").Check();
            worker.ReportProgress(50);
        }
        using (Session session = new Session())
        {
            // Connect
            session.Open(sessionOptionsDestination);

            // Upload files
            **session.PutFiles(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"\Downloaded_files_from_ftp\*", "public_html" + "/" + destDirectory).Check();**
            //                session.PutFiles(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"\Downloaded_files_from_ftp\*", destDirectory + "/").Check();

        }
        worker.ReportProgress(90);
        //deleteing local files
        DeleteLocalDirectory(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"\Downloaded_files_from_ftp");
        worker.ReportProgress(100);
    }
```

The line of code you would want to look at is

session.PutFiles(Environment.GetFolderPath        (Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"\Downloaded_files_from_ftp*", "public_html" + "/" + destDirectory).Check();

as you see it uploads the files but not all them so I think I have this wrong for the destination.

Help would be great.

Comment: did you try to make it @"\Downloaded_files_from_ftp*", "/public_html" + "/" + destDirectory).Check();   with / before the public_html

Comment: yes I have tried that

Comment: I tried that just now and I got a error in transferring although it did upload some files which makes no since to me.

Comment: I seem to remember from my FTP days a long time ago that when you connect you log into a default directory.  In FTP you can change the directory sending a command.  Do you have any commands available to you?  Can you change the directory to the one you want, then do the work?  If you cannot do that then, the FTP server is most likely preventing you.  FTP server security can be very strict.

Comment: I do not think there are any commands available I know the guy who did this for me is using the winSCP library